# Как в js обратиться из одного встроенного фрейма в другой?

Tags: javascript

Как в js обратиться из одного встроенного фрейма в другой?

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет про `<iframe>`, то боюсь что только через `parent`. Например можно вызвать функцию на странице содержащей iframe.

Для начала можно взглянуть на [Scripting Iframes](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/), там все достаточно понятно и доступно.

Все вышесказанное относится только если страницы и iframe-ы загружены с одного сайта.